# Is ehcache valid at application level or jvm level

Tags: spring-boot, ehcache

We have two Spring Boot applications that run in the same tomcat. One of them is an admin app where the configurations are updated and the second one uses those configurations for processing. So we want to cache those configurations for the second application so that it doesn't have to query the database frequently. But at the same time, we want the admin application to pull the information directly from the database. So is it possible to configure Ehcache for this? So wanted to know if the cache is specific to the application or JVM?